# magento join table collection

Tags: join, magento-1.5, magento

I'm customizing  Magento [FAQ extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-faq.html) for sort faq items by category.below collection is 
used to get all items active faq items.

```
$collection = Mage :: getModel('flagbit_faq/faq')->getCollection() 
              ->addStoreFilter(Mage :: app()->getStore())
              ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

there is relation table "**faq_category_item**"

Table structure:-

```
category_id    faq_id
   1              1
   2              2
   1              3
```

So I decide to join two tables.I unsuccess in that.
What i tried is below.

```
$tbl_faq_item = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('faq_category_item');

$collection = Mage :: getModel('flagbit_faq/faq')->getCollection() 
                  ->getSelect()
                  ->join(array('t2' => $tbl_faq_item),'main_table.faq_id = t2.faq_id','t2.category_id')  
                  ->addStoreFilter(Mage :: app()->getStore())
                  ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Whats wrong in this and how can i filter the particular category items.Please share some good links to learn Magento model collections.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The returned type from `getSelect()` and `join()` is a select object, not the collection that `addStoreFilter()` and `addIsActiveFilter()` belong to. The select part needs to occur later in the chain:

```
$collection = Mage :: getModel('flagbit_faq/faq')->getCollection() 
              ->addStoreFilter(Mage :: app()->getStore())
              ->addIsActiveFilter();
// Cannot append getSelect right here because $collection will not be a collection
$collection->getSelect()
           ->join(array('t2' => $tbl_faq_item),'main_table.faq_id = t2.faq_id','t2.category_id');
```

Comment: :good explanation thanks.can you share some link to learn about mage model collections.

Comment: You could start with [Alan Storm's tutorials](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections) or [his blog](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento).

Answer (score 4):

Try this function from

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract

 /**
 * Join a table
 *
 * @param string|array $table
 * @param string $bind
 * @param string|array $fields
 * @param null|array $cond
 * @param string $joinType
 * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
 */
public function joinTable($table, $bind, $fields = null, $cond = null, $joinType = 'inner')
{
```

So to join tables you can do like this:

```
$collection->joinTable('table-to-join','left.id=right.id',array('alias'=>'field'),'some condition or null', joinType(left right inner));
```

Comment: i'm getting error with joinTable function.Should i declare this function anywhere.

Comment: uhm...very strange. What output you get if try this snippet: print_r(get_class_methods(get_class($collection)))