# Joining multiple tables based on a custom attribute

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm trying to join two tables inside Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat,

```
$columns = array(
    // convert dates from UTC to current admin timezone
    'period'                         => $periodExpr,
    'store_id'                       => 'o.store_id',
    'order_status'                   => 'o.status',
    'orders_count'                   => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(o.entity_id)'),
    'total_qty_ordered'              => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(oi.total_qty_ordered)'),
    'total_qty_invoiced'             => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(oi.total_qty_invoiced)'),
    'total_income_amount'            => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_grand_total', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_canceled',0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate',0)
        )
    ),
    'total_revenue_amount'           => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_profit_amount'            => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((%s - %s - %s - %s - %s) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_paid', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced_cost', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_invoiced_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM(%s * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_canceled_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM(%s * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_canceled', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_paid_amount'              => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM(%s * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_paid', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_refunded_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM(%s * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_tax_amount'               => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_amount', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_canceled', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_tax_amount_actual'        => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((%s -%s) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_shipping_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_amount', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_canceled', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_shipping_amount_actual'   => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_discount_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((ABS(%s) - %s) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_amount', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_canceled', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    ),
    'total_discount_amount_actual'   => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
        )
    )
);

$select          = $adapter->select();
$selectOrderItem = $adapter->select();

$qtyCanceledExpr = $adapter->getIfNullSql('qty_canceled', 0);
$cols            = array(
    'order_id'           => 'order_id',
    'total_qty_ordered'  => new Zend_Db_expr("SUM(qty_ordered - {$qtyCanceledExpr})"),
    'total_qty_invoiced' => new Zend_Db_expr('SUM(qty_invoiced)'),
);
$selectOrderItem->from($this->getTable('sales/order_item'), $cols)
    ->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')
    ->group('order_id');

$select->from(array('o' => $this->getTable('sales/order')), $columns)
    ->join(array('oi' => $selectOrderItem), 'oi.order_id = o.entity_id', array())
    ->where('o.state NOT IN (?)', array(
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT,
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW
    ));
```

Can some please explain to me exactly what is happening inside:

```
$select->from(array('o' => $this->getTable('sales/order')), $columns)
    ->join(array('oi' => $selectOrderItem), 'oi.order_id = o.entity_id', array())
    ->where('o.state NOT IN (?)', array(
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT,
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW
    ));
```

From what I understand sales/order_item table is being joined with sales/order... (can someone please explain this syntax?) I'm trying to understand how to correctly join tables because I will need to join sales/order_grid with sales/order as well.

Thank you!

Comment: For understanding joins, http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ is a good start. Then you might want to see what is the SQL query behind `$select`, see if `var_dump($select)` prints the query.

Comment: see this question to learn how to join in magento: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337363/magento-join-table-collection